# Group ActiveRecord::Relation By Field Into Hash With Dictionary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm running an `ActiveRecord` query that returns a bunch of records.

Lets use this as an example

```
ad_account    campaign_id    impressions
1             1              500
1             2              8,800    
1             3              6,000
2             7              900
2             9              9,324
```

How do I turn these results into a hash with an array grouped by the ad_account?

So I want this

```
{"1"=>[{ad_account: 1, campaign_id: 1, impressions: 500}, {ad_account: 1, campaign_id: 2, impressions: 8,800}, {ad_account: 1, campaign_id: 3, impressions: 6,000}], 

"2"=>[{ad_account: 2, campaign_id: 7, impressions: 900}, {ad_account: 2, campaign_id: 9, impressions: 9324}]}
```

So basically every `ad_account` is the key and the values is an array of all of the fields.

How do I do this?

I've tried this but it doesn't work because it just overwrites

```
allCampaigns.each do |campaign| 

    hash[campaign.ad_account] = campaign 

end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) for this. For example:

```
Ad.all.group_by(&:ad_account)
# => { 1 => [#<Ad id: 1, ad_account: 1, campaign_id: 1, impressions: 500>,
#            #<Ad id: 2, ad_account: 1, campaign_id: 2, impressions: 8800>,
#            #<Ad id: 3, ad_account: 1, campaign_id: 3, impressions: 6000>],
#      2 => [#<Ad id: 4, ad_account: 2, campaign_id: 7, impressions: 900>,
#            #<Ad id: 5, ad_account: 2, campaign_id: 9, impressions: 9824>]}
```

This acts on the results of the query, on the enumerable object [`ActiveRecord::Relation`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html), it doesn't add a `GROUP BY` clause to your sql query.

Then, if you want that hash, specifically, you can add in [`serializable_hash`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serialization.html#method-i-serializable_hash)

```
Ad.all.group_by(&:ad_account).transform_values do |ads|
  ads.map do |ad|
    ad.serializable_hash(only: ['ad_account', 'campaign_id', 'impressions'])
  end
end
# { 1 => [{"ad_account"=>1, "campaign_id"=>1, "impressions"=>500},
#         {"ad_account"=>1, "campaign_id"=>2, "impressions"=>8800},
#         {"ad_account"=>1, "campaign_id"=>3, "impressions"=>6000}],
#   2 => [{"ad_account"=>2, "campaign_id"=>7, "impressions"=>900},
#         {"ad_account"=>2, "campaign_id"=>9, "impressions"=>9824}]}
```

Comment: Does the group_by affect the query? If it does I don’t want to group by the ad_account because I need the other fields. I will try this soon though!

Comment: Ah no it doesn't this is the `Enumerable#group_by` method ([`ActiveRecord::Relation`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html) includes `Enumerable`), it doesn't apply a `GROUP BY` clause to your query (for that you'd need ActiveRecord's `group` method), so it acts after the query is done and your objects are in the relation. didn't even cross my mind that there was an sql clause this might be confused with

Comment: Thank you very much! I will come back in an hour or so to mark this as the answer because it seems like exactly what will work for me. I appreciate your time